# URL to search in user's preferred search engine

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

Often I put links to searches in descriptions. The latest today was an article on graphics programming and I wanted to say something like,

> `If this works you should see no <a href="">Moiré patterns</a>`.

For the link I would often put [`https://google.com/search?q=Moiré pattern`](https://google.com/search?q=Moir%C3%A9%20pattern) but it occured to me it might be better to use a url that opens the user's preferred search engine. Does such a link/schema exist? (like `search://<query>`). If not, is there an proposed standard?

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a [feature request](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7652) on the HTML issue tracker from 2022 for this exact idea, which is still tagged *needs implementer interest* and didn't receive much love since it's been posted.

You may want to help provide your use-case so that it gets more traction, maybe.